# CSS Multibackground

Tags: html, css, modernizr

I am using multiple backround images width one div but it dosn't work in IE8.
Here is my css code:

```
.description-page #main-navigation ul{ 
   text-align:left;
   width: 451px;background:url(../images/menu-desing.png) no-repeat center 26px ,
                           url(../images/top-bar1.png) no-repeat center 0px ;
   height: 86px; z-index:100;padding-top: 9px;
}
```

Is there is any solution to this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple divs?

Comment: yes its possibe.but there is no workaround that i can use multiple  background withen one div?

Comment: it is, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS3pie to achieve this - http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following to achieve two backgrounds also for IE8:
You need only one element in the DOM, we will create the second one with the help of pseudo-elements, which work already in IE8 (not IE7).

```
.description-page #main-navigation ul { 
   text-align:left;
   width: 451px;
   background:url(../images/menu-desing.png) no-repeat center 26px;
   height: 86px; 
   padding-top: 9px;

   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}

/* Generate a new element with the second background, positioned on the same place like the original ul */
.description-page #main-navigation ul:before {
     background: url(../images/top-bar1.png) no-repeat center 0px;
     content: "";
     height: 86px;
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     width: 451px;

     z-index: -1;
}
```